# .net web forms application keeps logging out users

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I have a web forms application that I tested and works good locally.
When i upload it to a web server that hosts my site, it often just logs out users(they get redirected to the Account/Login.aspx page).

It doesn't produce an error in application so i dont know how to debug it properly but i think that it happens during page load event because users get logged out of the application sometimes(not always) after they make some changes, but the changes stay saved.

I think for some reason my session variable that keeps the login of the user gets reset.

If you have an idea or point me in some direction what and how i can investigate this issue, i would really appreciate it.

This is my code that runs on page load in my site Master.cs, maybe it helps:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/login.aspx");

            }
            if (!Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("Coach"))
            {
                if (Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("Administrator"))
                    Response.Redirect("~/AdminForm/AdminHome.aspx");
                if (Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("User"))
                    Response.Redirect("~/Form/Progress.aspx");
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank You!

Comment: sounds like a session timeout issue.  Might want to have a look at your web.config file and/or the IIS configuration of the server that it's being hosted on.

Comment: Do NOT use Session for authentication.... That's horribly insecure and you run into problems like these because IIS can recycle your worker process whenever it feels like (losing your session).  You should instead be using a FormsAuthentication token, and use role based access to control authorization

Comment: Erik, thank You for your answer. I changed my authentification from Session to cookies, but it still sometimes breaks. It doesn't redirect me to the login screen, but the home page for the role that has the cookie. For example, admin home page is"AdminHome". I click "AddUser" page, and i sometimes get redirected to "AdminHome", not always. Do You have an idea what can be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the timeout in your web.config file?

```
system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="50000000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
   </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: He's not using forms authentication, he's using a session variable to track his user id

Answer (score 0):

If you users are on the site for more than 20 minutes it will log out.  You can try web.config or IIS settings it will not help.

I found the best way to handle this is to use a KeepAlive page in and hidden iFrame that posts back to the server every 18 minutes. This will keep the worker process running and the site will never time out.

I have used this method on Internally Facing sites since the end users want to be on the site 8 to 5 without getting logged out.

[Sample project at this link](http://snippets.surfthru.com/post/Stop-ASPNET-Session-Timeouts)